# I'm using AOS library to give animation but it is not working on some div

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animations, aos.js

This is my html header

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this is my html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center aos-animate" >
   <div class="col-lg-6 text-center heading-section mb-5" data-aos="fade-up" >
    <h2 class="text-black mb-5">PHOTO GALLERY</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my JS

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init({
    duration:1000,
    offset:5,
    delay:10,
  });
  AOS.refresh();
</script>
```

I tried to give animation to a photo gallery with 10 images and it is not working can any one give me the solution.

Comment: lease put a complete runnable snippet of code into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue.
Try triggering AOS.refresh() on scroll, see if that helps. This worked for me:

```
  let scrollRef = 0;
  $(window).on("resize scroll", function () {
    // increase value up to 10, then refresh AOS
    scrollRef <= 10 ? scrollRef++ : AOS.refresh();
  });
```